# How to move files from a subdirectory into parent directory in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a nested directory like this...

```
dir1
   dir2
     file1.txt
     file2.txt
     file3.txt
```

I would like to move all the files within dir2 to dir1, like so...

```
dir1
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  file3.txt
```

What's the best way of doing this? I couldn't find anything in mercurial documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `hg help move` and use after reading all text `hg move dir1/dir2/file1.txt dir1/dir2/file2.txt dir1/dir2/file3.txt dir1/`